# Given integers $a$ and $b$ prove that if there exist integers $x$ and $y$ for which $ax+by=(a,b)$ then $(x,y)=1.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

**Problem**: Given integers $a$ and $b$ prove that if there exist integers $x$ and $y$ for which $ax+by=(a,b)$ then $(x,y)=1.$ Note that $(a,b)=\gcd(a,b).$

**Proof**: Suppose $(x,y)=m,$ where $m\in\mathbb{Z}.$ Then $y=mk_1$ and $x=mk_2$ for some $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $(a,b)=d$. We now have $m((a/d)k_1+(b/d)k_2)=1.$ Since both numbers are integers we can conclude that $m=1$ which completes the proof.

**Remark:** I am unsure about the last claim and would therefore, be grateful if someone could either rectify my proof or declare that it is correct.

Comment: What are you unsure about? If $mn=1$, and $n,m$ are positive integers, then $m=n=1$. Several proofs have been given at MSE, you can check some of them [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/230997/prove-that-if-a-b-x-y-are-integers-with-ax-by-gcda-b-then-gcdx-y-1), for example.

Comment: So, I've not made a mistake. I guess, I must be overthinking then..

Comment: No, I got it. $mn=1$ implies that $m=n=1$.

Comment: It is fine, i.e. $\ c\mid x,y\,\Rightarrow\,c\mid  x(a/d) + y(b/d) = 1\ $

Answer (score -1):

Your proof is correct. Here is an alternative. First of all, note that if $ax+by=c$ (where $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$ and $y$ are integers), then $(x,y)$ divides $c$ (since it has to divide any integer linear combination of $x$ and $y$).

Assume now that $(a,b)=1$ and $ax+by=1$. Then $(x,y)$ divides $1$, hence $(x,y)=1$. Now, if $d=(a,b)\neq 1$, then $\frac{a}{d}x+\frac{b}{d}y=1$ and $\frac{a}{d}$ and $\frac{b}{d}$ are integers, so $(x,y)=1$ by the previous case.